# Removing specific objects on Collision

Tags: lua, coronasdk

removing the coin im colliding whit seems a bit of a problem im got this :

```
local screenGroup = self.view
local options2 =
{
    --required parameters
    width = 16,
    height = 16,
    numFrames = 8,

    --optional parameters; used for dynamic resolution support
    sheetContentWidth = 128,  -- width of original 1x size of entire sheet
    sheetContentHeight = 16,  -- height of original 1x size of entire sheet
}

local imageSheet1 = graphics.newImageSheet( "items/coin.png", options2 )
-- Example assumes 'imageSheet' is already created using graphics.newImageSheet()

-- non-consecutive frames
local sequenceData1 =
{
    name="normal",
    frames= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, -- frame indexes of animation, in image sheet
    time = 600, --700           -- Optional, in milliseconds ; if not supplied, the animation is frame-based
    loopCount = 0        -- Optional ; default is 0
}

local coin = {}

local coinspawn = function()
    local i = display.newSprite( imageSheet1, sequenceData1 )

    i.x = display.contentWidth/2
    i.y = display.contentHeight/2
    i:play()
    i.collided = true
    i.name = "coin"
    physics.addBody(i, "dynamic", 
        {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, shape= shape2 ,filter=playerCollisionFilter } 
    )   
    --player.gravityScale = 0.5
    coinIntro = transition.to(i,{time=2000, x=display.contentWidth/2-50 ,onComplete=jetReady , transition=easing.OutExpo } ) --
    coin[#coin+1] = i

end 
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, coinspawn, 0 )

function coinPlus()
    for i = #coin, 1, -1 do
        if coin[i] ~= nil then
            local function dellcoin()
                if coin[i] ~= nil then
                    coin[i]:removeSelf()
                    coin[i] = nil
                end
            end
            transition.to( coin[i], {  time=100, alpha=0, onComplete = dellcoin} )
            break
        end
    end
end

local function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        local obj1 = event.object1; 
        local obj2 = event.object2; 

        if obj1.name == "playerpop" then
            if     obj2.name == "BGfrontFL1" then --helper()
            elseif obj2.name == "BGfrontFL2" then --helper()
            elseif obj2.name == "coin"   then coinPlus()
            end
        end
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

withs kinda works but it removes the last spawned coin and not the one in collision, how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `coinspawn` you create the coin and add it to `coin` table. It appears that your `coin` table will contain all spawned coins that have not been collided with (that seems to be your intention anyways). Then when a coin collides the `onCollision()` will get called, which will call `coinPlus()`. The latter then loops over all coins in `coin` table, starting with the latest spawned one (at end of table), and if it is not nil it starts a fade out with removal on completion of fade-out. This is surely not what you intend: you want to delete only the coin collided.

So the biggest problem is the way the coin that was involved in collision gets removed: looping over all coins, don't think it is necessary. You should try passing coin as arg to `coinPlus`:

```
if obj1.name == "playerpop" then
    if     obj2.name == "BGfrontFL1" then --helper()
    elseif obj2.name == "BGfrontFL2" then --helper()
    elseif obj2.name == "coin"   then coinPlus(obj2)
    end
end

function coinPlus(coinToRemove)
    local function dellcoin()
        coinToRemove:removeSelf()
        for i, coin in ipairs(coin) do
            if coin == coinToRemove then 
                coin[i] = nil
                break
            end
        end
    end
    transition.to( coinToRemove, {  time=100, alpha=0, onComplete = dellcoin} )
end
```

Another problem is your use of '#' operator: it is only to be used with tables that don't have "holes", so if you really do remove individual entries from your table (thus creating holes), then #coin will no longer work (that's why I used `ipairs`).